# loop through text and replacing * with span

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently struggling with a script that should replace some text and make it bold via css.

But my problem is, that the script isn't looping. It only takes the first text.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pthv/bL3a0svg/3/).

and here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function (i) {
$('.main:contains("*")').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('*', '<span class="highlight">'));
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('*', '</span>'));
});
```

});

Comment: Put your code here at SO.

Comment: u should use regular expressions ... this sites may help: http://regexr.com and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one also does the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function (i) {
    function replace(o) {
        $(o).html($(o).html().replace('*', '<span class="highlight">'));
        $(o).html($(o).html().replace('*', '</span>'));
        if ($(o).html().indexOf("*") >= 0) {
            replace(o);
        }
    }
    replace('.main:contains("*")');

});
```

Comment: I ended up with this solution. Thanks. I very much appreciate it. And thanks for all others comments. I'll take at look at Rex Demo as chsdk suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You should use regular expression with a `g` flag. Something like:

```
$('.main:contains("*")').html(function (_, html) {
    return html.replace(/\*(\w+)\*/g, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/az66jzf3/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function (i) {
    var $main = $(".main");
    var html = $main.html();
    var matches = html.match(/\*([^*]+)\*/g);
    for (var i=0, l=matches.length; i<l; i++) {
        var rep = "<span class='highlight'>" + matches[i].replace(/\*/g, "") + "</span>";
        html = html.replace(matches[i], rep);
    }
    
    $main.html(html);
});
```

```css
span.highlight{font-weight:bold;font-size:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    This is *just* a text.<br/>
    This is just *another* text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the above mentioned answers. My answer is mostly to explain what went wrong. When you used `:contains`, you basically looped through all the **elements** that contained the given text. Since main is the only element that matched the string `'*'` the loop only ran once. And the `$(this).html()` actually contained the entire string and since you used string replace twice, only the first two matches got replaced.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with js regex. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <p id="demo">Please *visit* me *visit* foo</p>

   <script>
      function myFunction() {
         var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
         var txt = str.replace(/\*(.+?)\*/g,"<b>$1</b>");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      }
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because

```
$('.main:contains("*")')
```

Returns the html element which contains * only once. And 'replace' only changes the first match. You have 2 replace's in your code so it replaces exactly 2 occurences of *.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **[Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)** `/\*(.+)\*/g`:

```js
$(document).ready(function (i) {
        $('.main').html($('.main').html().replace(/\*(.+)\*/g, "<span class=\"highlight\">$1</span>"));
});
```

```css
span.highlight{font-weight:bold;font-size:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    This is *just* a text.<br/>
    This is just *another* text.
</div>
```

It captures the matching text between two `*` and replace it with the same captured text enclosed by `<span>` element.

Take a look at this [**Regex DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/qW2rN0/1) to learn more about the capturing group matching.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pthv/bL3a0svg/3/
You can do it as follows easily.

```
var length = $('.main').html().length;
var check = 0;
var html = $('.main').html();

for (i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
 if (check === 0) {
   html = html.replace('*', '<span class="highlight">');
    check = 1;
 } else {
    html = html.replace('*', '</span>');
    check = 0;
 }
}
$(".main").html(html);
```